# Query to get start and end date that a row changed in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id  …   value   …   date_added
1   …   value1  …   some date
1   …   value2  …   some date
1   …   value3  …   some date
1   …   value4  …   some date
2   …   value5  …   some date
2   …   value6  …   some date
```

and I want something like this:

```
id  …   value   …   date_start      date_end
1   …   value1  …   some date       some date
1   …   value2  …   some date       some date
1   …   value3  …   some date       some date
1   …   value4  …   some date       some date
2   …   value5  …   some date       some date
2   …   value6  …   some date
```

so a query to get the date that each row got added to the table and the date when it got changed.

How do you do this?  Many thanks.

Comment: "get the date that each row got added to the table and the date when it got changed" You can use Timestamp fields for this. Search the MySQL documentation.

Comment: is your id column unique? where is primary key?

Comment: id column is a foreign key and it's not unique (one to many relationship).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the end date as the first change date after the current row:

```
select  id
,       value
,       date_start
,       (
        select  date_start
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.id = yt2.id
                and yt1.date_start < yt2.date_start
        order by
                yt2.date_start
        limit   1
        ) as date_end
from    YourTable yt1
```